# Using a Raspberry Pi to manage a bank of several hard drives

Tags: power-supply, file-server, hard-drive

I am looking to use a Raspberry Pi as a home file server. I have several hard drives, a Raspberry Pi, an unused computer case, and files that I need to store. I would like to mount all of my hard drives and my Raspberry Pi inside of an empty computer case that I have lying around and have my Raspberry Pi serve the files on all four of my hard drives to my home network.

I have a PC power supply that I can use to power all of the hard drives. What else will I need to get and do to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have never done what you want to achieve, this might do the trick.

First of all what type of hard-drives do you have?

I'm assuming that you have SATA hard drives. You can get yourself SATA to USB cables, or [something like this](http://alaqsa.com.pk/sata-to-usb.html), so that you can connect your hard drives to the USB ports of Raspberry Pi.

The issue here is that there are just two USB ports, so now you have to buy a self-powered USB Hub to connect more than two USB devices to your Raspberry Pi.

Now, follow [these instructions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-add-usb-storage-to-the-raspberry-pi/) to connect your Hard drives to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks, I have both Sata and Ata hard drives. I have USB connectors for both though.

Comment: You should include the instructions from the link to avoid link-rot.  Also, you should comment on the question beforehand if you have questions for the OP, not ask the questions in an answer.